# How to detect in a generator that it has been interrupted from outside

Tags: python, exception, generator

I have this generator:

```
def gen():
    rounds = 0
    for x in xrange(10):
        rounds += 1
        yield x
    print 'Generator finished (%d rounds)' % (rounds)
```

If I call it normally:

```
for x in gen():
    pass
```

I get the expected:

```
Generator finished (10 rounds)
```

But if I interrupt the generator, I get nothing:

```
for x in gen():
    break
```

I would like to get:

```
Generator interrupted (1 rounds)
```

Is it possible to detect, in the generator itself, that it has been interrupted from outside? Is there any `Exception` that I could catch to detect this event?

Comment: I doubt there is an `Exception`.  All that happens is that the function stops being called after only one calling.  As such control will never be returned to the function to execute that `print`.

Comment: No, there is no exception here - you simply stopped looping over it. You could handle it outside by retaining a reference to the generator and making sure `next(gen)` raises `StopIteration`, but can't tell from inside - the generator just waits until it's called again or garbage collected.

Comment: It's not what you asked, but you *could* wrap the generator in a context manager, and use `__exit__` -- something like: http://ideone.com/X7637V

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot, because a generator's default behaviour is to be interrupted *all the time*. A generator is *constantly* paused, **every time it yields a value.**

In other words, your understanding of how generators work is incorrect. The looping over a generator is entirely outside the control of the generator; all it is tasked to do is produce a next value, which unpauses the code until the next `yield` expression is executed.

As such, when no next value is being requested, the generator is paused and cannot execute code to 'detect' that it is not being asked for another value.

What happens when you call a generator function is this:

- A special [generator iterator object](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods) is returned. No code in the function body is executed.
- Code *outside the generator iterator* may or may not use it as an iterator. Each time a new value is needed, [`generator_object.next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.next) is called.
- When the `.next()` method is called, the function body is run, until a `yield` expression is encountered. The function body is paused and the result of the `yield` expression is returned as the result of the `.next()` method.

You can *explicitly* send messages or raise exceptions in your generator function with the [`generator_object.send()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) and [`generator_object.throw()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.throw) methods, but no such messages or exceptions are sent when not iterating over the generator object.

One thing you *could* look for is the `GeneratorExit` exception thrown inside your generator function when the generator object is closed; see the [`generator_object.close()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.close):

> Raises a `GeneratorExit` at the point where the generator function was paused

When a generator object is *garbage collected* (e.g. nothing references it anymore) the `generator_object.close()` method is called automatically:

```
def gen():
    rounds = 0
    for x in xrange(10):
        rounds += 1
        try:
            yield x
        except GeneratorExit:
            print 'Generator closed early after %d rounds' % rounds
            raise
    print 'Generator finished (%d rounds)' % rounds
```

Demo:

```
>>> def gen():
...     rounds = 0
...     for x in xrange(10):
...         rounds += 1
...         try:
...             yield x
...         except GeneratorExit:
...             print 'Generator closed early after %d rounds' % rounds
...             raise
...     print 'Generator finished (%d rounds)' % rounds
... 
>>> for i in gen():
...     break
... 
Generator closed early after 1 rounds
```

This only works because the returned generator object is only referenced by the `for` loop, and is reaped the moment the `for` loop ends.

Comment: I think `GeneratorExit` is good enough for what I am looking for. I guess it won't work as expected if I have a reference to the generator lying around, but for the simple case of just looping over it in-place will always produce the expected result.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: take into account that *when the generator is closed* is Python implementation dependent. CPython uses reference counting and the generator object is reaped immediately, but in Jython or IronPython there can be a significant delay between the object no longer being referenced and garbage collection clearing it.

Answer (score 0):

A `contextmanager` would allow you to provide code to be executed on generator exit.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
rounds = 0

@contextmanager
def on_generator_exit():
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        global rounds
        print 'Generator finished (%d rounds)' % (rounds)

def gen():
    with on_generator_exit():
        global rounds
        rounds = 0
        for x in xrange(10):
            rounds += 1
            yield x

for x in gen():
    break
```

Output:

```
Generator finished (1 rounds)
```